# Drop down list values from Database (PHP/SQL)

Tags: php, html, sql

Im just wondering wether the code below is the most efficient for populating a drop down list with information from the Database in php/sql.

```
                //GET ALL SONGS FROM DATABASE
                $query = $dbConn->query("SELECT track_id, track_title FROM track");

                echo '<select class="feild" name="songDrop">';//MAKE THE DROPDOWN 

                echo '<option value="none">Choose the Song to add</option>';

                // Loop through the query results, displaying the options one by one
                while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                     echo '<option value="'.$row['track_id'].'">'.$row['track_title'].'</option>';
                }

                echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Yes. Nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: Try to write `PHP inside HTML` rather than `HTML inside PHP`. It will look cleaner and easier to understand. You can also use `alternative syntax of while()` when writing inside HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
                //GET ALL SONGS FROM DATABASE
            $query = $dbConn->query("SELECT track_id, track_title FROM track");

            echo '<select class="feild" name="songDrop">';//MAKE THE DROPDOWN 

            echo '<option value="none">Choose the Song to add</option>';

            // Loop through the query results, displaying the options one by one
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                 echo '<option value="'.$row['track_id'].'">'.$row['track_title'].'</option>';
            }

            echo '</select>';
```